# parallel eclipse does not recognize true number of processors when using MPI

Tags: c++, eclipse, parallel-processing, mpi, processors

I have the following code that when executed with eclipse 2020.12, the output is this: "Hello from rank 0 out of 1"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int data;

    if (rank > 0) {

        MPI_Recv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                cout << "Rank "<< rank<< " has received message with data " << data
                        << " from rank " << rank-1
                        << endl;
    }

    cout << "Hello from rank " << rank<< " out of " << size<< endl;

    if (rank < size-1) {
        data = rank*rank;

        MPI_Send(&data, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

But, when I execute this through command line with following commands, it works as expected

```
mpic++ -o name name.cpp
mpiexec -np 4 ./name
```

it shows 4 hello , which is number of my cores. I was wondering why eclipse cannot recognize but the sampe cpp file with another way of execution works fine! and the output will be :

```
Hello from rank 0 out of 4
Rank 1 has received message with data 0 from rank 0
Hello from rank 1 out of 4
Rank 2 has received message with data 1 from rank 1
Hello from rank 2 out of 4
Rank 3 has received message with data 4 from rank 2
Hello from rank 3 out of 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new run configuration from the Parallel Application template. On the **Resources** tab, set **Target System Configuration** to *Generic OpenMPI Interactive* or *Generic MPICH2 Interactive* based on whether your MPI implementation derives from Open MPI or MPICH. Set **Connection Type** to *Local*. Then set the number of processes in the **Basic Options** tab.

[image]

Switch to the **Application** tab and put the path to the executable file in **Application program**. Just click the **Browse** button next of it and navigate to either *Debug* or *Release* directory and select the executable there.

[image]

The Run button should now turn blue and you can press it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Project and:

- click with the second mouse button
- select `Run As` > `Run Configurations`
- select Parallel Applications
- click with the second mouse button
- click of new configuration
- click on the newly create configuration
- click on Resources
- from the "Target System Configuration" dropdown menu select for instance "Generic Remote Interactive"
- in connection type select local (since you will run the eclipse locally)

[image]

- switch to tap Application
- in application program enter the path to you mpirun *e.g.,* `/usr/bin/mpirun`

[image]

- finally switch to Arguments
- in `application argument` pass the argument "-np 4"

[image]

- click run